# Getting a default value on ion-select with *ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

App is Ionic 4 with Angular 6...
I have an `ion-select` that is part of a form.  It populates with a list of your teammates using an `*ngFor`.  I am trying to use the `selected` attribute based on the [ionic 4 docs select-option](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option).

```
<ion-select *ngFor="let member of team" [(ngModel)]="model.assignedTo" #assignedTo="ngModel" name="assignedTo" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
    <ion-select-option>{{ member.firstName }} {{ member.lastName }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

I have been having lots of trouble. I have tried different syntaxes like `[selected], value, [value], selected, etc.`.  I would just like to select the option where `member.firstName == 'Me'`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the syntax to:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="model.assignedTo" #assignedTo="ngModel" name="assignedTo" okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let member of team" [value]="member.id">{{ member.firstName }} {{ member.lastName }}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

on JS side:

```
this.model.assignedTo = this.account.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why we have `[(ngModel)]`, set the value you want for that variable. Also you are having your `*ngFor` on `select`, though it should be on the `option`:

TS:

```ts
model = { assignedTo: 'Me'}
team = [{firstName: 'You'}, {firstName: 'Me'}];
```

HTML:

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)">
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="model.assignedTo" #assignedTo="ngModel" name="assignedTo">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let member of team" [value]="member.firstName">
      {{ member.firstName }}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</form>
```

Comment: Made the changes you recommended (moving the ngfor and making model.assignedTo = 'Me'), unfortunately, the option still does not display as the default, although, it submits as the default when the form is submitted

Comment: Please create a demo if you can, I tried this now in an ionic 4 project, and it works just fine for me.